# Database design for my small CMS system - need for my exam

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I'm trying create design for small cms system for my exam in school but I get stack.

Basicly I would like to have table "Content".

Item in "Content" table can be type of: "Article", "Event", "Static Page" and so on. 
These types will be stored in table "ContentType"

For particular "ContentType" I would like to add few fields. 
Every field can be used only once - which means if I have field: "StaticPageBody" and it is added to "Static Page", then I can't add it into "Event". I must create new field: "BodyForEvent".

To this field I would like to add "Formatter" which is part of my pain.
For example I will have 2 formatters: FormatterText & FormatterImage - for these 2 formatters I will have different columns.

FormatterText will have only 1 column: Body
FormatterImage will have different columns: Url, Alt

I don't know how to create relation between table "Field" and tables started with "Formatter*".

I hope that you understand me. Check please screenshot. On this link: [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIDgdwGDsdHbVNIeURLaHBsWTA/view?usp=sharing) - is also sql script or .bak file for creating my TestDb with some data.

[image]

Thanks for help.